# Cannot Select one dropdown in a group of several ... element not clickable issue

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to select one dropdown in a group of several elements and or some reason ONE of the dropdowns cannot be selected.  I get the error :  *=> {"message":"unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (433, 15). Other element would receive the click: ...\n*
[Screen shot from the product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDphD.png)

The only control I cannot select is the PRIMARY LANGUAGE dropdown.  I am trying to do it with XPATH.  the addtrlno element is the Trailer Number dropdown several elements away from the Primary Language.  I hate including tons and tons of code but I will try to include a LOT and see if maybe there is an errror one of you can spot.

```
    <div id="addtab-1">
                <form id="addForm" name="addForm" method="POST">
                    <table class="colx1 vh noborder bgwhite">
                        <tr>
                            <th>CPL</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="cpl" onBlur="decipherCPL()" style="width:480px" maxlength="120" id="addcpl"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>CPL2</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="cpl2" style="width:480px" maxlength="120" id="addcpl2"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>CPL3</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="cpl3" style="width:480px" maxlength="120" id="addcpl3"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>CPL4</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="cpl4" style="width:480px" maxlength="120" id="addcpl4"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>UUID</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="uuid" style="width:480px" maxlength="50" id="adduuid"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Trailer Number</th>
                            <td>
                                <select name="trlno" id="addtrlno">
                                <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="F1">F1</option>
                                <option value="F2">F2</option>
                                <option value="F3">F3</option>
                                <option value="F4">F4</option>
                                <option value="F5">F5</option>
                                <option value="F6">F6</option>
                                <option value="F7">F7</option>
                                <option value="F8">F8</option>
                                <option value="F9">F9</option>
                                <option value="ComicCon">ComicCon</option>
                                <option value="CinemaCon">CinemaCon</option>
                                <option value="CineEurope">CineEurope</option>
                                <option value="CineAsia">CineAsia</option>
                                <option value="ShowEast">ShowEast</option>
                                <option value="Selected Scene">Selected Scene</option>
                                <option value="Roadshow">Roadshow</option>
                                <option value="SXSW">SXSW</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Maccs CPL Version</th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="maccscpl" style="width:480px" maxlength="80" id="maccstrlcpl"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>DCHub CPL Version</th>
                            <td>
                                <nobr>
                                    <input type="text" name="dchubcpl" style="width:480px" maxlength="80" id="adddchubcpl"/>
                                    <a href="javascript:calcDCHubCPLAdd()"><img src="/images/wand.png" border="0" alt="Calculate DCHub CPL Name" title="Calculate DCHub CPL Name"/></a>
                                </nobr>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="desc" style="width:480px" maxlength="30" id="addDesc"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Flat Scope</th>
                            <td>
                                <select name="flatscope" id="addflatscope">
                                    <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="Flat">Flat</option>
                                    <option value="Scope">Scope</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Two D</th>
                            <td>
                                <select name="twod" id="addtwod" onChange="addTwoDChange()">
                                    <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="2D">2D</option>
                                    <option value="3D">3D</option>
                                    <option value="COMBO">COMBO</option>
                                    <option value="2D 48FPS">2D 48FPS</option>
                                    <option value="3D 48FPS">3D 48FPS</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Audio</th>
                            <td>
                                <select name="audio" id="addAudio">
                                    <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="5.1">5.1</option>
                                    <option value="7.1">7.1</option>
                                    <option value="COMBO">COMBO</option>
                                    <option value="ATMOS">ATMOS</option>
                                    <option value="AURO">AURO</option>
                                    <option value="Stereo">Stereo</option>
                                    <option value="Mono">Mono</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Primary Language</th>
                            <td>
                                <select name="language" id="addLang">
                                    <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
                                                                        <option value="1">ALBANIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="2">ARABIC</option>
                                                                        <option value="59">ARABIC FRENCH</option>
                                                                        <option value="61">AUDIO DESCRIPTION</option>
                                                                        <option value="70">AZERI</option>
                                                                        <option value="3">BOSNIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="4">BULGARIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="5">CATALAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="6">CHINESE - CANTONESE</option>
                                                                        <option value="7">CHINESE - MANDARIN PRC</option>
                                                                        <option value="8">CHINESE - MANDARIN SIMPLIFIED</option>
                                                                        <option value="9">CHINESE - MANDARIN TRADITIONAL</option>
                                                                        <option value="10">CHINESE - TAIWANESE</option>
                                                                        <option value="11">CHINESE - TAIWANESE MANDARIN</option>
                                                                        <option value="12">CROATIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="13">CZECH</option>
                                                                        <option value="14">DANISH</option>
                                                                        <option value="15">DUTCH</option>
                                                                        <option value="16">ENGLISH</option>
                                                                        <option value="74">ENGLISH FOR AUSTRALIA</option>
                                                                        <option value="75">ENGLISH FOR INDIA</option>
                                                                        <option value="72">ENGLISH FOR PHILIPPINES</option>
                                                                        <option value="17">ESTONIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="64">ESTONIAN RUSSIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="18">EUSKARA</option>
                                                                        <option value="19">FINNISH</option>
                                                                        <option value="60">FINNISH SWEDISH</option>
                                                                        <option value="20">FLEMISH</option>
                                                                        <option value="21">FRENCH</option>
                                                                        <option value="22">FRENCH - CANADIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="69">GEORGIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="23">GERMAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="24">GERMAN - SWISS</option>
                                                                        <option value="63">GERMAN FRENCH</option>
                                                                        <option value="25">GREEK</option>
                                                                        <option value="62">HARD OF HEARING</option>
                                                                        <option value="26">HEBREW</option>
                                                                        <option value="27">HINDI</option>
                                                                        <option value="28">HUNGARIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="29">ICELANDIC</option>
                                                                        <option value="65">INDIAN ENGLISH SUBS</option>
                                                                        <option value="30">INDONESIAN BAHASA</option>
                                                                        <option value="31">ITALIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="32">JAPANESE</option>
                                                                        <option value="33">KAZAKH</option>
                                                                        <option value="34">KOREAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="35">LATVIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="66">LATVIAN RUSSIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="36">LITHUANIAN</option>

                                                                        <option value="67">MACEDONIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="37">MALAY BAHASA</option>
                                                                        <option value="76">MANDARIN SIMPLIFIED MALAY BAHASA</option>
                                                                        <option value="38">MONGOLIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="39">NORWEGIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="40">POLISH</option>
                                                                        <option value="41">PORTUGUESE - BRAZILIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="42">PORTUGUESE - EUROPEAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="43">ROMANIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="44">RUSSIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="45">SERBIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="46">SLOVAK</option>
                                                                        <option value="47">SLOVENIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="48">SPANISH - ARGENTINIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="49">SPANISH - CASTILIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="73">SPANISH - COLOMBIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="50">SPANISH - LATIN AMERICAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="51">SPANISH - MEXICAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="52">SWEDISH</option>
                                                                        <option value="53">TAMIL</option>
                                                                        <option value="54">TELUGU</option>
                                                                        <option value="55">THAI</option>
                                                                        <option value="56">TURKISH</option>
                                                                        <option value="57">UKRAINIAN</option>
                                                                        <option value="68">URDU</option>
                                                                        <option value="58">VIETNAMESE</option>
                                                                        <option value="71">VIETNAMESE KOREAN</option>
                                                                    </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Secondary Language</th>
                            <td>
                                <select name="language2" id="addSecLang">
                                    <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="0">None</option>
                                                                            <option value="1">ALBANIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="2">ARABIC</option>
                                                                                <option value="59">ARABIC FRENCH</option>
                                                                                <option value="61">AUDIO DESCRIPTION</option>
                                                                                <option value="70">AZERI</option>
                                                                                <option value="3">BOSNIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="4">BULGARIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="5">CATALAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="6">CHINESE - CANTONESE</option>
                                                                                <option value="7">CHINESE - MANDARIN PRC</option>
                                                                                <option value="8">CHINESE - MANDARIN SIMPLIFIED</option>
                                                                                <option value="9">CHINESE - MANDARIN TRADITIONAL</option>
                                                                                <option value="10">CHINESE - TAIWANESE</option>
                                                                                <option value="11">CHINESE - TAIWANESE MANDARIN</option>
                                                                                <option value="12">CROATIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="13">CZECH</option>
                                                                                <option value="14">DANISH</option>
                                                                                <option value="15">DUTCH</option>
                                                                                <option value="16">ENGLISH</option>
                                                                                <option value="74">ENGLISH FOR AUSTRALIA</option>
                                                                                <option value="75">ENGLISH FOR INDIA</option>
                                                                                <option value="72">ENGLISH FOR PHILIPPINES</option>
                                                                                <option value="17">ESTONIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="64">ESTONIAN RUSSIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="18">EUSKARA</option>
                                                                                <option value="19">FINNISH</option>
                                                                                <option value="60">FINNISH SWEDISH</option>
                                                                                <option value="20">FLEMISH</option>
                                                                                <option value="21">FRENCH</option>
                                                                                <option value="22">FRENCH - CANADIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="69">GEORGIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="23">GERMAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="24">GERMAN - SWISS</option>
                                                                                <option value="63">GERMAN FRENCH</option>
                                                                                <option value="25">GREEK</option>
                                                                                <option value="62">HARD OF HEARING</option>
                                                                                <option value="26">HEBREW</option>
                                                                                <option value="27">HINDI</option>
                                                                                <option value="28">HUNGARIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="29">ICELANDIC</option>
                                                                                <option value="65">INDIAN ENGLISH SUBS</option>
                                                                                <option value="30">INDONESIAN BAHASA</option>
                                                                                <option value="31">ITALIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="32">JAPANESE</option>
                                                                                <option value="33">KAZAKH</option>
                                                                                <option value="34">KOREAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="35">LATVIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="66">LATVIAN RUSSIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="36">LITHUANIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="67">MACEDONIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="37">MALAY BAHASA</option>
                                                                                <option value="76">MANDARIN SIMPLIFIED MALAY BAHASA</option>
                                                                                <option value="38">MONGOLIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="39">NORWEGIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="40">POLISH</option>
                                                                                <option value="41">PORTUGUESE - BRAZILIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="42">PORTUGUESE - EUROPEAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="43">ROMANIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="44">RUSSIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="45">SERBIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="46">SLOVAK</option>
                                                                                <option value="47">SLOVENIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="48">SPANISH - ARGENTINIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="49">SPANISH - CASTILIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="73">SPANISH - COLOMBIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="50">SPANISH - LATIN AMERICAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="51">SPANISH - MEXICAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="52">SWEDISH</option>
                                                                                <option value="53">TAMIL</option>
                                                                                <option value="54">TELUGU</option>
                                                                                <option value="55">THAI</option>
                                                                                <option value="56">TURKISH</option>
                                                                                <option value="57">UKRAINIAN</option>
                                                                                <option value="68">URDU</option>
                                                                                <option value="58">VIETNAMESE</option>
                                                                                <option value="71">VIETNAMESE KOREAN</option>
                                                                        </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Dubbed</th>
                            <td>
                                <select name="dubbed" id="addDubbed">
                                    <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="SUB">SUB</option>
                                    <option value="DUB">DUB</option>
                                    <option value="OV">OV</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Vendor</th>
                            <td>
                                <select name="vendor" id="addVendor" onChange="vendChange()">
                                    <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
                                                                        <option value="5">Arri</option>
                                                                        <option value="15">CinemaDelivery</option>
                                                                        <option value="9">DCinex</option>
                                                                        <option value="2">Deluxe</option>
                                                                        <option value="3">Dolby</option>
                                                                        <option value="6">Eclair</option>
                                                                        <option value="13">Gofilex</option>
                                                                        <option value="10">Imagica</option>
                                                                        <option value="7">IMAX</option>
                                                                        <option value="12">Manual Push See Rules</option>
                                                                        <option value="1">Motion Picture Solutions</option>
                                                                        <option value="8">Producer Approval</option>
                                                                        <option value="11">Q-Tech</option>
                                                                        <option value="4">Technicolor</option>
                                                                        <option value="14">Unique</option>
                                                                    </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: what is the error message you are getting for this ? Select primary_lang = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='language']")));
     primary_lang.selectByIndex(0);System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='language']")).getLocation().toString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

`{"message":"unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (433, 15). Other element would receive the click"` can be caused for different factors. You can address them by either of the following procedures:

**1. Element not getting clicked**

Try to use `Actions` Class:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id1"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

> OR

Try to use `JavascriptExecutor`:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse1.executeScript("scroll(250, 0)"); // if the element is on top.
jse1.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)"); // if the element is at bottom.
```

> OR

```
WebElement myelement = driver.findElement(By.id("id1"));
JavascriptExecutor jse2 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse2.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", myelement);
```

**2. The page is getting refreshed before the element gets clickable.**

In this case induce some `wait`.

**3. Element is present in the DOM but not clickable.**

In this case add some `ExplicitWait` for the element to be clickable.

```
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("id1")));
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: WOW.  Well the very first one worked.  with the ACTION class I was able to select the dropdown.  Now I want to select an item *in* the dropdown.  Do I need to use action again to select a specific item in the list?

Comment: @WayneHazle Great !!! Now you may consider using `Select` class to select an option. Can you consider to Accept the Answer please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try following code & see if it works:

```
WebElement primaryLang = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form#addForm > table.colx1.vh.noborder.bgwhite  td select#addLang"));

Select primaryLangDDN = new Select(primaryLang );
primaryLangDDN.selectByVisibleText("DANISH");
```